# Powershell Pass .csv values to set-ADuser cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to populate extensionAttribute1 for users based on a .csv file that contain samAccoutName and ExtensionAttribute1 columns.

Bellow is the code I'm using for this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Attribcsv=Import-csv “D:\Exports\sales.csv”
ForEach ($User in $Attribcsv)
{
Get-ADUser -Identity $User.samAccountName | set-ADUser -add @{extensionAttribute1=$User.extensionAttribute1}
}
```

After running the code I'm receiving this error:

```
set-ADUser : Multiple values were specified for an attribute that can have only one value
```

.csv file sample:

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSJ0H.png)

Can someone tell me what I am missing please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed `$User.extensionAttribute1` in a subexpression `$()` so the value gets expanded.

Also I would recommend adding a test to see if you can find the user before trying to set its property:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Attribcsv = Import-csv 'D:\Exports\sales.csv'
foreach ($User in $Attribcsv) {
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.samAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($adUser) {
        $adUser | Set-ADUser -Add @{extensionAttribute1 = $($User.extensionAttribute1)}
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No user with SamAccountName '$($User.samAccountName)' found.."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfectly. 

Side note: If the user already has the extensionAttribute1 set, you must use "-replace" to change it.