# could i get some advice with a Set-ADuser command

Tags: powershell

anyone happen to know how i can run this command against a CSV I.E. multiple users

set-ADUser "Username" -Clear homeDrive, homeDirectory, profilePath

Comment: See [`Set-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser) and [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72990832/edit) your question to be more specific what you want to and add e.g. sample `csv` input data, see: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will find a lot of examples here at stackoverflow, see e.g.: [Powershell Pass .csv values to set-ADuser cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72075951/1701026).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a CSV file with each user's username in a column named `Username`, you'd do something like this:

```
Import-Csv path\to\users.csv |ForEach-Object {
  Set-ADUser $_.Username -Clear homeDrive,homeDirectory,profilePath
}
```

Comment: thanks ever so much i dont suppose you could help with another issue im trying to remove users from an AD Group in Bulk so far ive tried this but it doest work

Comment: @MarkStogdale Feel more than free to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :) If this particular answer solves your `Set-ADUser` problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left